# Android - Error Retrofit Multiple file upload

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm trying to upload multiple files to a server backed with php and i'm facing the below error. I would appreciate it if you could help

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main

    Process: com.app.link, PID: 22253
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: @Part annotation must supply a name or use MultipartBody.Part parameter type. (parameter #2)
        for method FileUploadService.upload
```

This is my interface class

```
public interface FileUploadService {
    @Multipart
    @POST("MultiPartUpload.php")
    Call<ResponseBody> upload(
            @Part("description") RequestBody description,
            @Part List<MultipartBody.Part> file);

}
```

And this is the upload method

```
private void uploadFiles(List<Uri> fileUris){
        List<MultipartBody.Part> parts = new ArrayList<>();
        Integer fileSize = fileUris.size();

        for(int i = 0;i<fileSize;i++)
        {

                if (fileUris.get(i) != null) {
                    parts.add(prepareFilePart("file"+i, fileUris.get(i)));
                }
        }

        RequestBody description = createPartFromString("this is description");
        FileUploadService service = ServiceGenerator.createService(FileUploadService.class);
        Retrofit.Builder builder =  new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://192.168.1.5/RestApi/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());
        Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();
        FileUploadService client = retrofit.create(FileUploadService.class);
        Call<ResponseBody> call = client.upload(description,parts);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
          

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was sloved after I updated retrofit to the latest (2.9.0) version.

Comment: please add the Retrofit version that helped you

Comment: com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0